# CSS: Child of a child

Tags: html, css

OK, so this works in jsFiddle, but not on our site (not uncommon).  What I'm wondering is if there is an alternate way to do what I want.  What I want to do is to change the width of the first "class:three" div in the first "class:two" div, and only that one.

If this were only on a single page, I'd simply assign an ID and be done with it.  Unfortunately, that is not the case.  This format is on dozens of pages that will need to have a link to a CSS file to override the defaults.

The problem lies in the last item of the CSS.  I can get all first children divs to shorten without problem.  But that's not what I need.  I only need the first one of the first set to be shortened.  The problem seems to be that when I do a *#ID class1:first-child class2:first-child*, the class1 piece is cancelling the reformatting statement.  I have checked all of the CSS, from the default formatting down to any inline formatting, and there is nothing that should be overriding what needs to happen.

I have tried :first-child, :nth-child(1) and :eq(0) with the same results.  As I said, this works using jsFiddle, but not on our site.  So, if anyone knows an alternative, I'm open to suggestions.

```html
<style>
  #one {background-color:red; padding:10px;}
  .two {background-color:white; padding:10px;}
  .three {background-color:red; padding:10px; margin:10px;}

  #one .two:first-child .three:first-child {width: 75%;}
</style>

<div id="one">
  <div class="two" >
    <div class="three" >
      <span>This is a test</span>
    </div>
    <div class="three" >
      <span>This is a test</span>
    </div>
    <div class="three" >
      <span>This is a test</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="two" >
    <div class="three" >
      <span>This is a test</span>
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      <span>This is a test</span>
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      <span>This is a test</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you say it works on jsfiddle but not on your site, I don't think we can't reliably solve this problem without seeing the specifics of your site

Comment: Agree, Works on SO code snippets aswell

Comment: You said you've "checked all the CSS". Did you view the element in question in the style inspector? Does it show your style? You'll see the `width` property being overridden by something else, which is where your problem lies.

Comment: doe it work on any of the pages on your site ? are you sure they are all linking to this css ?

Comment: If you *really* want child of a child and not descendant of a decendant try `#one>.two:first-child>.three:first-child {width: 75%;}`

Comment: @mattit if possible can you share the url of the original page.

Answer (score 0):

> This format is on dozens of pages that will need to have a link to a CSS file to override the defaults.

Just a guess, but you might just need to use `!important`, even though it's not the best form. The CSS hierarchy is inline, tag selector (`td`, `span`, etc.) ID, class. So what you're using to override is at the bottom of the food chain. Using `!important` would bring it up to the very top, assuming `!important` isn't being used anywhere else on a higher level.

Using `!important` isn't the best form, but if you have a huge site that would be a pain to change your layout to a point where you didn't need it... well, they have it in the standard for a reason, so you might as well put it to good use.

Comment: I will emphasise that `!important` is an absolute LAST resort. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Comment: It does not appear that I need to use `!important` on this if I use a .class1:nth-child(odd) call.  

One of these days, they'll move all of our site into the 21st Century...and then _maybe_ normal CSS formatting will work.

Answer (score 0):

After further experimentation, which seems to fit the crazy config of our site, the following appears to work.  Why it worked when *#ID class1:**first-child** class2:first-child* wouldn't still baffles me.

```
#ID class1:nth-child(odd) class2:first-child
```

Comment: In that case you have a more specific style overiding it from somewhere: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/. Check the element when it is broken using Chrome Developer tools or Firebug For Firefox to see what styles are being applied to the element.

Comment: Great article!  Thanks, Jon.  As to the issue at hand, it does not appear that anything is overriding the width.  It's as though it's not recognizing the .class1:first-child call.  If I get rid of the :first-child piece it works, but for all class2:first-child items.

Our site (a major retailer) has had bandaid after bandaid, so it doesn't surprise me that only certain things work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your css code with the below one

```
#one:first-child .two:first-child .three:first-child{
    width: 75%;
}
```

Comment: Did not work, with and without `!important`.  It's the way our site works.  Something that *should* work doesn't always do so.